# Campaing/adventure recomendations for a new company

Tags: published-adventures, game-recommendation, campaign-settings, the-one-ring

I will be mastering a "The one ring" group and i'm looking for adventures or campaigns recomendations. I found there is a lot of content but i'm a little confused about what level is each campaing designed for. This is a new party with mostly unexperienced players.

As a 1st contact, I thought of running :
The marsh bell (From the book) and Words of the wise (Free PDF)

I don't have time to create a custom campaing so I would much preffer taking a campaign book (i heard they are great), but i'm really lost. Is "Tales From Wilderland" a good start? Should I create some custom adventures before starting a book campaign?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site Jose! Take the [tour] when you have a moment. Unfortunately, recommendation questions are off topic here, but you may be able to get some good help at a more traditional discussion forum, see [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) for our curated list.

Comment: For a bit of explanation, recommendation questions are considered off topic because this site aims for objective answers, and recommendations are inherently subjective and leads to arguments that can't be resolved with facts.